# Is it possible to enable mitm script at runtime?

Tags: mitmproxy

I have a question about mitmproxy (mitmdump).

What I need is to change mitmproxy configuration at runtime.
I have some scripts, let's say:

```
scripts/
  test-case-1.py
  test-case-2.py
```

and I need to load (or unload) a proper script while mitmdump is running.
Unfortunaly, running `mitmdump -s /scripts/test-case-1.py` returns

```
/scripts # mitmdump -s ./test-case-1.py 
Error starting proxy server: OSError(98, 'Address in use')
```

Is it possible to somehow call the mitmdump to append a proper script?

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Python level addons (and scripts usually contain Mitm addons) can be added and removed at run-time. But AFAIK in mitmdump there is no interface for doing so (not sure about mitmproxy/mitmweb).

One possibility would be to build a plugin based on the [ASGI-Flask example addon](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-examples/#wsgi-flask-app). It provides a virtual host that can be accessed via Mitmproxy and if a certain path on that server like `example.com/enableaddon1` you can enable or disable a second addon.
Alternatively you can simply change a global variable that makes your second add-on behave differently.

This requires a bit of Python programming but it gives you a lot flexibility.